# Make JQuery fire when I scroll down the page 900px

Tags: jquery

I have a small JQuery script that I want to run when the user scrolls down the page by 900px. I have this so far:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
           if( $(window).scrollTop > 900){
                    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $('.single').text() }, {
                      duration: 1000,
                      step: function () {
                        $('.single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                      }
                    });

                    //SEVERAL VALUES

                    $('.Count').each(function () {
                      jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $(this).text() }, {
                        duration: 1000,
                        step: function () {
                          $(this).text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                        }
                      });
                    });
           }
        });     
    }); 
    </script>
```

I now have the above but it doesn't seem to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   if( $(window).scrollTop > 900){
     // Your code to execute when the window is scrolled more than 900px
   }
});
```

Comment: I have amended my code, however, it doesn't seem to work. Not sure why?

Comment: Make a fiddle, I don't know what you are trying to do :)